# Segmentation fault with multithreading (ncurses)

Tags: c, multithreading, ncurses

Having the following struct and global var:

```
typedef struct Column{
    char * text;
    int size; 
} Column;

Column * screen;
```

And this thread function:

```
void * thread_function(void * msg){
    Info *mesg = (Info *)msg;
    int col = mesg->c;

    int count = 0;
    while (count < MAX_ELEM){
        if (rand() % 2){ 
            screen[col].text[count] = ' ';
            screen[col].size++;    
            count++;
        } 
        else{
            screen[col].text[count] = 'a';
            screen[col].size++;    
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

In the main function after I join the threads I start printing the content of the `screen`

```
int row = 42; // num of rows on the screen
while(true){
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i<col; i++){
            int j = screen[i].size - 1; // print only up to already assign value
            int k = 0;
            while (j >= 0 && k < row){
                mvprintw(k,i,"%c",screen[i].text[j]);
                refresh();
                j--;
                k++;
            }
        }
        refresh();
    }
```

The issue is that some runs execute normally, while others generate a Seg fault err after a few iterations of the `while(true)`(Note: at least something is always printed). If I remove `mvprintw()` from the `while(true)` the seg fault never occurs. What can be the issue?

P.s. Please do not post answers which are related to mutex, as this is an assignment and I would prefer to correct the problem I have, rather reimplement the idea especially when it can be performed without mutex.

**Edits:**

allocation of global var `screen` (part of main)

```
screen = malloc(col * sizeof(Column *));
i = 0;
    for (; i<col; i++){
        screen[i].text = malloc(MAX_ELEM * sizeof(char));
        screen[i].size = 0;
    }
```

Output screen at seg faults:

```
                                                              a a             Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Output screen at no seg fault:

```
         a                            a  a              a             a     aa
                        a  a                                        a
```

Comment: can u plz post some code regarding the allocation of `Screen` and `Screen->text`

Comment: Have you tried running your code under a debugger? also, a self contained example would probably help

Comment: @Hasturkun I'm using an editor for the code, debugging manually, as it is noted in the question, `mvprintw()` and hence `screen[i].text[j]` causes the seg fault, although shouldn’t as `screen[i]` exists and `j` is the size, which get's incremented in main only after a value is actually assigned to the next slot.

Comment: Silly question, but is there any chance you run your thread twice on the same `screen[col]`? that would make `screen[col].size > MAX_ELEM`. I'm only mentioning this because your thread function uses two counters, `count` and `size`. Only one of these gets zeroed in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel that

`screen = malloc(col * sizeof(Column *));`

to be

```
screen = malloc(col * sizeof(Column));
```

because `sizeof(Column *)` would return only the size of pointer